# How to add CircularProgressIndicator when loading web page using flutter_inappwebview?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new in flutter,

I tried to add a CircularProgressIndicator while waiting to the web page to load,
and then the page display and the circular indicator dosen't show on screen.

where it's should be? maybe in onLoadStart function below?

Source code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

class CoursesInformation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CoursesInformationState createState() => _CoursesInformationState();
}

class _CoursesInformationState extends State<CoursesInformation> {
  InAppWebViewController webView;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
        child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('מידע על קורסים'),
          centerTitle: true,        
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: InAppWebView(
            initialUrl:
                "https://shoham.biu.ac.il/BiuCoursesViewer/MainPage.aspx",
            initialHeaders: {},
            initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
              crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                  debuggingEnabled: true,
                  preferredContentMode: UserPreferredContentMode.DESKTOP),
            ),
            onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
              webView = controller;
            },
            onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

            },
            onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) async {

            },
          ))
        ])),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `onProgressChanged` parameter and show the loader. You can also use `LinearProgressIndicator` (check commented code). Check the following example

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

void main() {
  // it should be the first line in main method
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark()
          .copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47)),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: CustomPage());
  }
}

class CustomPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return CustomPageState();
  }
}

class CustomPageState extends State<CustomPage> {
  InAppWebViewController webView;

  double progress = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('מידע על קורסים'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
            child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: InAppWebView(
                initialUrl:
                    "https://shoham.biu.ac.il/BiuCoursesViewer/MainPage.aspx",
                initialHeaders: {},
                initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                  crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                      debuggingEnabled: true,
                      preferredContentMode: UserPreferredContentMode.DESKTOP),
                ),
                onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                  webView = controller;
                },
                onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

                },
                onLoadStop:
                    (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) async {
                },
                onProgressChanged: (InAppWebViewController controller, int progress) {
                  setState(() {
                    this.progress = progress / 100;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: _buildProgressBar()
            ),
          ],
        ))
      ])),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildProgressBar() {
    if (progress != 1.0) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
// You can use LinearProgressIndicator also
//      return LinearProgressIndicator(
//        value: progress,
//        valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.orange),
//        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
//      );
    }
    return Container();
  }
}
```